# What CPU, RAM, Chipset requirements for real-time transcode two 1080p ts streams to common formats?

Tags: cpu, requirements, transcode

I aim to build a home media streaming server, and I have a lot of recordings from my satellite receiver in ts format (it's a Dreambox DM8000 HD PVR and it directly writes the transport stream to disc when recording). So almost all my recorded movies are full-hd 1080p .ts files.

I want to use tversity as the software to stream the contents to my devices (PS3 for the son, Mac (with XMBC) for my wife, my Xbox 360, iOS devices floating around...), and so the software will need to transcode the data so that it can be played.

So, what CPU power is required when I want to be able to watch a 1080p movie on my xbox when, at the same time, my son wants to watch another 1080p movie on the PS3? It needs to be able to do both full HD transcodings in realtime, with a bit of reserve (if required) for fast forward / rewind.

Do you think there are special requirements to the board/chipset too and how much RAM is suggested for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any system with quad core CPU and 4 GB of RAM should be able to transcode 2 1080p simultaneously. Just make sure you have fast enough network connection.

Comment: Network is gigabit ethernet, except for the last few meters wifi (n) to the iOS devices.

Comment: So, for instance, even the slowest Core i5 (2.5 GHz) should be able to do this?